# tool to give user ability to query database without any ability to alter data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a Power User who knows the database very well and has become a great asset since we gave him access with SQL Server Management Studio. Unfortunately, we also gave him a user/pwd used by all Development which carries ability to change data.

Without going into all the wrongs behind having such a privileged db-user and giving such access an end user, is there a tool that would give the user ability to query without any ability to update/insert/drop/ or anything else?

Comment: actually you can do it on SQL Server Management Studio, alter the privilege of the user to just `SELECT` only.

Comment: Why can't you just revoke DDL privileges and grant `SELECT` only?

Comment: You want to deny privileges to that particular user, but not to the rest of the team that uses that user/password?

Comment: i wish i could. I gave him the user user by ALL development. this user is in all our internal connection strings and SSMS connections.

Comment: `a user/pwd used by all Development` this was the first mistake. Have all users their very own credentials. Yes, this bad decision will cost you time and efforts to fix. Nevertheless, you won't make this mistake again.

Comment: `this user is in all our internal connection strings and SSMS connections` This was the second mistake.

Comment: all users having their own credentials would be a good practice to implement. But short of instituting whole-sale changes immediately, i need a way to limit this one user. Ideally with a read-only tool.

Comment: `i need a way to limit this one user` so not the other people using **exactly the same credentials**? That won't go. The cheapest you can do is to get someone sit by the Power User, and slap him whenever non-select statements are typed...

Comment: Agreed. Keep in mind, this is development servers, not production. I won't pretend it's fine, but it's a situation I inherited, never had time to fix, and now made slightly worse. Now I'd like a way to let this user keep his access b/c his knowledge has been of great help, but want to stop him from causing problems.

Comment: admitting all bad practice and fault, and acknowledging ppeterka's humor, is there a tool that allows querying only?

Comment: In theory you could write your own tool that uses an [application role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998(v=sql.100).aspx) to limit the permissions when someone uses that specific tool. But really that doesn't solve anything because your users seem to have access to logins with more permissions anyway. Until you fix that issue there is absolutely no point in trying to limit their permissions in just one application; if they can't do something they will just fire up SSMS and do what they want.

Comment: @DaveA I think you won't find one. How should the server know that the session just opened with the same credentials os the "other" sessions are to be treated differently? I'm afraid no quick fix exists... Maybe you could have a network admin restrict the access to the DB in question to only a range of IP addresses (your developers, who rightfully access the DB with write rights), and give the Power User his own - accurately restricted, read only - access credentials.

Comment: Pondlife, you're onto an idea we've been floating. Slapping together an app that allows him to query only. I was hoping there was a tool out there already and could save us time. But that may well be the end result.

Comment: ppeterka, I wasn't looking for a robust tool that would 'slap' one user. Rather, I was wondering if any read-only tools were available.

Comment: Well, a separate app is on option but it's a pointless one. You're asking how to make sure someone can only enter a house through the front door while they still have the back door key. Yes, you can ask nicely (or make threats) but ultimately you're trusting them to do what you ask them. The only way to be sure is to take the key away. And as you can see from all these comments, the 'workarounds' probably involve just as much work as fixing the real problem.

Comment: Pondlife, I agree. We'll probably end up taking away SSMS and slapping together a query tool.

Comment: Why not just create a new login for him with the right permissions and change the password of your dev account?

Comment: All input constructive and appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the user probably does not want to change the database -- for his/her protection as well as yours.

Just enable this user's login using Window to have read-only access.  Or, set up another read-only user and give it to the power user.  At the extreme, you may need to change the password of your super user account.

I would recommend in the mean time that you set up a development group, give the group privileges, and assign the developers to the group.  They can then login through that id. Perhaps one day, you'll be able to disable your super user account.  For now, you should think about ways to work around it.

Comment: many changes are overdue. Good security policies and practices are lost or overlooked in the rush to deliver and this particular project was over-promised and timeline too crunched.

Comment: @DaveA . . . Gosh, I've never been there ;)